# Do different guard weapons have different abilities?

Tags: invisible-inc

According to the [Invisible Inc Wikia](http://invisibleinc.wikia.com/wiki/Enemies), different guards have different types of weapons. For example, the basic FTM Security Guard carries a pistol, while the Elite Guard version carries an SMG.

Do these different gun types have different abilities?

The wiki page explicitly says whether or not an enemy has armor penetrating weapons (with regards to drones), but I didn't see anything like that for the human guards.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not 100%, but short answer is no.

I've been playing Invisible Inc for a long while now and haven't seen any difference in gun behavior for guards. Your agents (unless it has changed very recently) don't get body armor so it really is all the same. Only real difference between guards and firepower mainly has to do with grenades, these can pretty much take either take you out or locate where you are.

The big reason why drone guns has a stat for penetration is because it's possible to hack these and shoot things, like that one troublesome guard with pen2 armor hunting you down ;) .